# how to convert a a hex byte stored as string to hex byte in python

Tags: python, mongodb, hex, pymongo, decode

i have a list of hex byte that have stored as string in Mongodb because Mongodb doesn't support hex byte my data is :

```
'topics': ['0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef', '0x00000000000000000000000077337dfe579a03a07a475870db443d65127f0769', '0x0000000000000000000000003b6d0dd29a60ff5ea96b54e60fbb0d71da80ef78']
```

i have to change to be like :

```
'topics': [
HexBytes('0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62'), HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000006036f4ea42a2d6d8b9a0120f0a7b95faf21e82d3'), HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000004ba84d2ca525aa578f8e097acd4141dfd52b3e74'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000e54c65316e8967c25c1357773b5e85bc063b7efd')
]
```

i have used the binascii , hex(int(topics[0],int16)) but didn't work is there any way to do it

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `HexBytes`? Is it imported somewhere?

Comment: Maybe `[bytes.fromhex(topic[2:]) for topic in topics]`?

Comment: i am using an API to get data and it returns me hexbytes when i use the type for check the type of the retuen data it was '<class 'hexbytes.main.HexBytes'>' dear @tdelaney

Comment: The class looks like the [HexBytes Package](https://hexbytes.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hexbytes.html). So, after `from hexbytes import HexBytes`, something like `topics = [HexBytes(hb) for hb in topics]` might work?